# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the FeedService (?, FeedItemTypeRepository, FeedTypeRepository, RefundService)

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm rather new to node js & nest , what i basically have is a FeedModule (with FeedRepository\FeedItemTypeRepository\FeedTypeRepository) and a RefundModule (with a RefundService)

here's the current state :

FeedModule :

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Feed, FeedRepository]),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([FeedItemType, FeedItemTypeRepository]),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([FeedType, FeedTypeRepository]),
    RefundModule
  ],
  controllers: [FeedController],
  providers: [FeedProvider, FeedService, FeedItemTypeRepository,FeedTypeRepository,],
  exports: [FeedService,],
})
export class FeedModule {
}
```

FeedService :

```
@Injectable()
export class FeedService {

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(FeedRepository)
    private readonly feedRepository: FeedRepository,
    private readonly feedItemTypeRepository: FeedItemTypeRepository,
    private readonly feedTypeRepository: FeedTypeRepository,
    private readonly refundService: RefundService,

    // private readonly timeService: TimeService,
  ) {
  }}
```

RefundModule :

```
@Module({
  imports: [

    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Refund, RefundRepository]),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([RefundCurrency, RefundCurrencyRepository]),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([RefundStatus, RefundStatusRepository]),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([RefundType, RefundTypeRepository]),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Feed, FeedRepository]),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([FeedItemType, FeedItemTypeRepository]),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([FeedType, FeedTypeRepository]),


    FlightModule,
  ],
  controllers: [RefundController, refundsByFlightController,RefundDetailsController],
  providers: [RefundProvider, RefundService, FlightService],
  exports: [FlightService, RefundService],
})
export class RefundModule {
}
export class RefundCurrencyModule {
}
export class RefundStatusModule {
}
export class RefundTypeModule {
}
export class UserModule {
}
```

any information will do on this one , what am i missing ? is it okay to call a few repositories in one Module\Service

I have tried many changed but to no effect if anyone can point me to the right direction . Thanks for the helpers !

More Info : 
-FeedRepo:

```
@EntityRepository(Feed)
export class FeedRepository extends Repository<Feed> {
  getFeedItemsByUserId(id: number): Promise<Feed[]> {
    return this.createQueryBuilder('feed')
      .select([
        'feed.id',
        'feed.userId',
        'feed.type',

        'feed.createdAt',
      ])
      .leftJoinAndSelect('feed.itemType', 'itemType')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('feed.fkRefundFeed', 'refunds')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('refunds.currency', 'refundCurrency')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('refunds.status', 'refundStatus')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('refunds.type', 'refundtype')

      .leftJoinAndSelect('refunds.fkFlightRefund', 'flight')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('feed.fkFlightFeed', 'flights')
      .where({ userId: id })
      .getMany();
  }

  async addFeedItem(feed:Feed) {
   await this.createQueryBuilder().insert().into(Feed).values(feed).execute();
 }
}
```

-FeedItemType:

```
@EntityRepository(FeedItemType)
export class FeedItemTypeRepository extends Repository<FeedItemType> {

  getFeedItemType(id: number): Promise<FeedItemType> {
    return this.findOne(
      {
        join: {
          leftJoinAndSelect:
            { key: 'refund.fkFlightRefund' },
          alias: 'refund',
        },
        where: { id: id },
      },
    );
  }
}
```

FeedType:

```
@EntityRepository(FeedType)
export class FeedTypeRepository extends Repository<FeedType> {

  getFeedType(id: number): Promise<FeedType> {
    return this.findOne(
      {
        join: {
          leftJoinAndSelect:
            { key: 'refund.fkFlightRefund' },
          alias: 'refund',
        },
        where: { id: id },
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, stop making your code unreadable. You can put multiple entities in `forFeature` array :) 
Can you show your FeedRepository code?

Comment: noted , added the FeedRepo \ FeedItemTypeRepo \ FeedTypeRepo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `@nestjs/typeorm` `@InjectRepository` requires an entity that was passed to `TypeOrmModule.forFeature()` because the forFeature method creates repositories with a token with the entity prototype (probably something like `repository_${Entity.constructor.prototype}`). In your case using the entity Feed, the `forFeature` method has already created you a repository with a token similar to `repository_Feed`.

When you use `@InjectRepository()` all you're doing is injecting the class with the token `repository_Feed`. In your case you're using a custom repository. So your token will not be `repository_Feed` but instead `FeedRepository`.

> Confusing sometimes I know but I think of the container like a key value store and the 'provide' or 'token' as the key and the class as the value. When we use Inject or Inject${insert name here} we're asking for those values using the key! So `Nest cannot resolve provider` usually means the key doesn't exist in the container!

So to your code! We don't want to use `@InjectRepository` because we've got a custom repo. Use a metatype instead.

```
export class FeedService {
  constructor(
    private readonly feedRepository: FeedRepository,
  ) {}
}
```

And that's it!

Hope the explanation helped!

Answer (score 1):

The FeedRepository should also be added to providers.
I don't really know the code, but the forFeature() should contain list of entities, so you can remove the repositories from there.
And if you use custom repository there's no need to inject it, you can ask for it from the typeorm manager/connection. I haven't tried this but according to the documentation:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/custom-repository.md

Comment: made the changes suggested for better coding but didn't solve it yet

Comment: if you want to inject FeedRepository you should add to providers in FeedModule

Comment: this is my providers now : providers: [FeedProvider, FeedService,RefundService,FeedRepository,FeedItemTypeRepository,FeedTypeRepository] still giving the same error..

Comment: add @Injectable() to FeedRepository. I dont know if nestjs handles the EntityRepository correctly.

Comment: I think the custom repositories not handled this way. So you should add to constructor without InjectRepository annotation, since injectrepository waits for entity.